# Product Information Tabs are missing in new product

Tags: tabs, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9. and problem is this i have already some product in magento admin when i edit any product I find all options but when I create new product I couldn't find some tabs for your better understanding and difference please see attached screenshots and help me resolve this issue.

[Product Information Form with Missing Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vButP.png)

[Product Information Form with Full options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKdqZ.png)

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think the user you have logged in with does not have enough permissions to edit existing products. Check user permissions in the system tab

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue might be the website scope (try changing it to store view or global or default)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.
I logged in from admin user and website is running in Default scope.
I guess there is something wrong in DB or in attributes. I don't know. I need an expert opinions.